# True or False statements and negations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have three statements below:

Given $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$

$\left(\forall x\right)\left(\exists y\right)\left(x\le y\right)$

$\left(\forall x\right)\left(\exists!y\right)\left(xy=y\right)$

$\left(\forall x\right)\left(\exists y\right)\left(xy=0\right)$

The first one is true because for all $x$ in the universal set $\mathbb{R}$, there will always be a greater number than $x$. This is so obvious that I think a proof is unnecessary.

The second is false because the true statement should be $(∃!x)(∀y)(xy = y)$.

The third one is true because for $y=0$, the statement is true.

Am I correct in all cases? Thank you so much!

Comment: Re: Correctness: Look more closely at the second item. Being able to find a statement which is very similarly worded which is correct doesn't tell you anything about the truth of your original statement. You need to do a bit more work here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solutions for 1 & 3 are correct. You could justify the first by citing the Archimedean Principle.

EDIT: My mistake on 2, I forgot about $0$.

You are correct that 2 is false, but there is a need for further justification. There is an issue of uniqueness on 2 to worry about:

For any $x$, notice that $xy = y$ is true whenever $x =1$ or $y = 0$. Hence the *uniqueness* itself fails, since for $x =1$, this is true for any $y$.

Comment: I don't know why someone is consistently downvoting here. This answer is nice and to the point. (+1)

Comment: Not a voter on this answer yet, but it's *not entirely correct*, which is a perfectly good reason for a downvote. Look more closely at the second item.

Comment: @KReiser You are right! My mistake.

Comment: @VanishingPhilosopher So for 2, the answer is "the statement is true because there is an unique y = 0 such that xy = y for all x"? To be clear, is the statement true or false, friend? Because x = 1 is one case for xy = y, and y = 0 is another case.

Comment: @hanamontana The statement is false since the uniqueness fails. Right, we are talking about FOR ALL x's. So for $x\neq 1$, the statement is true; $y=0$ is the unique number that works. However, for $x=1$, any y works, so it is not unique. $!$ means unique. Since it doesn't hold for ALL x's, the statement fails